# Unpacking Open Zeppelin starter pack warnings and errors

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin, command-line

When unpacking OZ starter pack I get a couple of 100 lines of red code (warnings) and then it ends with a bunch of errors (see below).

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sha3@1.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sha3@1.2.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm running

```
Truffle v5.1.13
Node v13.8.0
```

I have no idea what to make of these errors, so any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: try to run it as sudo

Comment: Are you on windows? Try with node 10, from my experience web3 does support node 12 nor node 13 (there is a dependency that fails to compile).